# GWT: ListEditor incorrectly tries to validate entities removed form the list

Tags: java, gwt, bean-validation, requestfactory, gwt-editors

The problem is that ContactDocuments removed with `editor.getList().remove(index)` are still passed for validation making it impossible to save edited Contact. For example `requestContext.save()` will fail with onConstraintViolation if I add new ContactDocument with `editor.getList().add()` then immideatly remove it because of @NotNull violation on some fields.

I have simple relation: Contact has many ContactDocuments. I'm trying to edit Contact with request factory and editors framework. ContactDocuments is annotated with JSR-303 for basic validation.

My ListEditor for ContactDocuments collection:

```
public class ContactDocumentListEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<ListEditor<ContactDocumentProxy, ContactDocumentEditor>>, HasRequestContext<List<ContactDocumentProxy>> {
private RequestContext requestContext;

interface ViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ContactDocumentListEditor> {}
private final static ViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(ViewUiBinder.class);

private final ListEditor<ContactDocumentProxy, ContactDocumentEditor> editor = ListEditor.of(new DocumentEditorSource());

@UiField
VerticalPanel container;
@UiField
Button addContactDocumentButton;


@UiHandler("addContactDocumentButton")
void addContactDocumentButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    addNewContactDocument();
}


public ContactDocumentListEditor() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

private class DocumentEditorSource extends EditorSource<ContactDocumentEditor> {
    @Override
    public ContactDocumentEditor create(final int index) {
        final ContactDocumentEditor documentEditor = new ContactDocumentEditor();
        documentEditor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                removeDocumentEditor(index);
            }
        });
        container.insert(documentEditor, index);
        return documentEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ContactDocumentEditor subEditor) {
        container.remove(subEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setIndex(ContactDocumentEditor subEditor, int index) {
        container.insert(subEditor, index);
    }
}

@Override
public ListEditor<ContactDocumentProxy, ContactDocumentEditor> asEditor() {
    return editor;
}

@Override
public void setRequestContext(RequestContext ctx) {
    requestContext = ctx;
}

private void addNewContactDocument() {
    ContactDocumentProxy newDocument = requestContext.create(ContactDocumentProxy.class);
    editor.getList().add(newDocument);
}

private void removeDocumentEditor(int index) {
    editor.getList().remove(index);
}
}
```

My Presenter to drive it:

```
    final ContactRequestContext contactRequestContext =  contactRequestContextProvider.get();
    contactRequestContext.save(contact);
    driver.edit(contact, contactRequestContext);
    driver.flush().fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void response) {
            // success 
        }

        @Override
        public void onConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {
            for (ConstraintViolation violation : violations) {
                logger.info("Contact constraint violation: " + violation.getPropertyPath() + " = " + violation.getMessage());
            }
            driver.setConstraintViolations(violations);
        }
    });
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Either defer the creation of the *real* proxy by using a *double* (create a class that implements your proxy interface, create an instance of that class rather than an RF proxy, and on or after *flush* create the real proxies to replace the *fake* ones; that way you'll never create a proxy that won't be sent to the server).</del>

Or if possible only validate your objects as part of others, never individually (don't validate a `ContactDocument` on its own, only as part of validating a `Contact`, using `@Valid` on the property containing the `ContactDocument`s): this can be accomplished using a `ServiceLayerDecorator` overriding the `validate` method, possibly combined with a `@GroupSequence` on either or both classes and the `ServiceLayerDecorator` validating using a specific group other than `Default`.

Related issue: [Cannot remove proxy from RequestContext editing context](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6685)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas!
Your answer is right on the spot. However I have another problem.

I have implemented my proxy interface:

    public class ContactDocumentFakeProxy implements ContactDocumentProxy {
    @Override
    public EntityProxyId<?> stableId() {
        return null;
    }
}

but then when I add it to list with `editor.getList().add(new ContactDocumentFakeProxy())` IllegalArgumentException is thrown by AbstractRequestContext.checkStreamsNotCrossed(). It seems `AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(object)` can not create AutoBean from my implementation.

Comment: What's the stacktrace? When is the exception thrown?

Comment: I'll try `ServiceLayerDecorator` approach. Thanks for the help!